# How do I find the system's disk capacity?

Tags: hard-drive, aix, dfs, capacity

I run the command df -g to get the GB block sizes in the second column (left to right). If I want to get the total capacity for all hard disks, which command should I use?

OS is AIX.

Comment: Which OS? I'm guessing Linux?

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in `lspv | awk '{print $1}'`
do
    echo $i
    lsattr -El -a size_in_mb $i
done
```

Or via ODM:

```
odmget -q"name like hdisk* and attribute=size_in_mb" CuAt
```

Answer (score 2):

Total size of all disks (sum). Output in GB.

```
TOTAL=0; for DISK in $(lspv | awk '{ print $1 }');do SIZE=$(bootinfo -s $DISK); TOTAL=$(echo "$TOTAL + $SIZE"|bc); done; echo "$TOTAL / 1024" | bc
```

**Used Commands** 
lspv: lists all disks 
bootinfo -s: gives you the real size of the disk 
bc: used for calculating

Comment: Thank you for this.  However, we do prefer at least a little explanation (such as what command you're getting the data from, I assume lspv plus bootinfo) and the reason for the scripting around it.  Nonetheless, an upvote to you.

Answer (score 1):

For AIX try the following, which does NOT need to be run as root:

```
get_conf DISK_SIZE /dev/hdisk0
```

The output will be returned in MB.

Comment: In case someone's still looking for the answer, it is getconf now in AIX 7.2

Answer (score 0):

The following command will help you to find total size of each hdd on your system.

```
fdisk -l  | grep Disk
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you didn't ask this directly but `df -h` lists created partition sizes which is sometimes more useful.

Answer (score -1):

Not sitting in front of an AIX system, but try this:

```
df --total -h
```

Edit: this won't work in AIX. But I'll leave this here for anyone else who might need it on GNU systems.

Comment: AIX commands don't support GNU like parameters.

Comment: hmmmm .... I thought that was too easy ...